# speed up PyTextRank for summarizing a document

Tags: python, spacy, summarization, pytextrank

I need to summarize documents with spacy-pytextrank, what is the best approach to make it faster without increasing the resources of the machine? 
I was thinking of parallelizing the computation using [concurrent futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). Then apply texrank to each chunk. I know that in this way texrank would evaluate each chunk independently, but I don't see this as a problem if the chunks are sufficiently long. 
Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Also @Ire00 if you want to post related questions on our GH repo for `pytextrank` then more of the committers can join in on discussions

Answer (score 0):

Note that `pytextrank` is a *pipeline component* in `spaCy` so any parallel processing needs to take into account how `spaCy` runs and its architecture. Notably, there is one `doc` per large-ish "chunk" of text (i.e., source document) and it probably does not make sense to parallelize by reusing the `doc` objects, but instead focus on reusing the `nlp` object and parallelizing by running several `doc` pipelines concurrently.  That's how other projects have handled this kind of situation you're describing.

As one of the committers on `pytextrank`, yes in fact we having been looking at ways to leverage concurrent futures in Python to help parallelize internally within the library. Also, we had a side project for a customer where we used similar Python concurrency through `ray` although the built-in `asyncio` in later versions of the language provide most of what we'd needed.

To be candid, there are probably better ways to summarize text using language models, though the extractive approach in `pytextrank` is unsupervised and *fast*. We had not been prioritizing much development for summarization features; however, there seems to be lots of interest.

What would help would be to know: Where do the resources get bottlenecked in your use case?  In other words, is utilization of multi-cores low, or is the application I/O-bound?  Then we can prioritize how to leverage language features for concurrency.

Comment: Thanks @Paco. I've tried to use multiprocessing as suggested in SpaCy documentation, but i got the error: "TypeError: can not serialize 'BaseTextRank' object" (Afterwards I saw that there is an open issue about this in pytextrank). 
I know that there are better way to summarize, but currently my need is to have a fast and unsupervised approach and I am having promising results with pytextrank. 
If you have any code example with pytextrank in parallel would be great. 
Thank you :)

Comment: This appears to be happening in several cases in `spaCy` and some of the GH issues point to using `srsly` https://github.com/explosion/srsly to resolving serialization issues.  We'll try that.

Comment: Hi @Paco, I've tried using srsly, but i got the same serialization error if n_process>1. Currently I am using joblib to prallelize and it works. But the problem is that I have to load the the pipeline in each task. It is faster, but I don't think it is the most efficient approach...

Comment: Definitely, there are better ways than joblib. I'll take this to friends at Explosion and ask for guidance. FWIW, serialization errors such as this were our biggest community problem when Spark hit its hypergrowth period a decade ago, so it's not like this is unknown :)